# CONNECT CONNACK Endless Loop - Moscapsule MQTT on SwiftUI iOS

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, mqtt

I'm making an app using SwiftUI and MQTT, through the Moscapsule Library. Everything is going fine when I run the app in the Simulator, the MQTT works perfectly. However, when I run the app in my iPhone, I keep getting an endless loop of CONNECT and CONNACK messages (like 30 messages/second) in the Xcode output window. It doesn't crash, but it doesn't publish messages correctly either.

The app works perfectly on the iPhone Simulator.

Here's what I get:

[image: error]

Some code:
[image: code]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Would you show related code?

Comment: I added the piece of my code that starts the MQTT Client; It's wrapped by a class I made, then called in the ContentView.

Comment: Please do no post images of code/logs, post the actual text and use the toolbar to format it. Images can be hard to read and are impossible for people who use screen readers.

Comment: You shouldn't allocate long-loved objects (such as your `myMQTT` instance) directly in the view as views are continually disposed of and recreated in SwiftUI. You should create a single instance of this object and pass it to your views, possibly via the environment or some other model object.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I managed to create it through the environment after a long search of how to do that. It now works mostly well! Sorry for the delay, didn't have free time but thanks!